# Meaning of '수반'

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I was watching one of 탐사보도 세븐's episodes today and it was about the China-North Korea border. I don't know if I can post this here but here goes. On one of the buildings was a red banner that read '위대한 김정은동지를 수반으로 하는 당중앙위원회를 목숨으로 사수하자!' I can't find much about the word '수반' in English online and figured I'd post on here asking about it. I feel the word has something to do with being the 'head' of some body / group, but I may be wrong. My interpretation of the banner would therefore be something along the lines of 'let's protect with our lives the party's central committee that great comrade (KJU) is head of!'

For the record, I have NO sympathy for the Kim dynasty or the North Korean government and its regime. I was just simply watching this program and whilst reading the banners on the buildings out of curiosity, I found a new word. Please don't misunderstand my intention behind making this post. I'd simply like to know the meaning of '수반' and if anybody could give me more examples that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: You are correct about the meaning of 수반(首班) here. [首](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A6%96) means *head*; [班](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8F%AD) means *class* or *group.*

Answer (score 1):

수반 is a general word meaning a head or a leader of a political entity of any kind, not limited to dictatorship.
The most common usage example is '대한민국의 대통령은 행정부의 수반이다.'